# Jquery price slider can't scroll in mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I'm making the price slider in my wordpress site, I'm using Jquery price slider from [this](https://www.bladephp.co/price-range-slider-using-jquery-css-mysql-php) link. When I check on my desktop the slider's working well but on my phone I can't scroll the slider.

Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 40,
    max: 210,
    values: [40, 210],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#amount").html("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
      $("#min_price").val(ui.values[0]);
      $("#max_price").val(ui.values[1]);
    }
  });
  $("#amount").html("$" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
    " - $" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<label class="field_label" for="slider-range">Price Slider:</label>
<div class="price_slider_wrapper">
  <div id="slider-range"></div>
  <div class="price_slider_amount">
    <input type="text" id="min_price" name="min_price" value="40" data-min="40" placeholder="Min price" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" id="max_price" name="max_price" value="210" data-max="210" placeholder="Max price" style="display: none;">

    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <p>Price: <span id="amount"></span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible workaround is using jQuery UI Touch Punch.

You could try to include jQuery UI Touch Punch after jQuery and jQuery UI.

```
<script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you explain me in detail a little more?

Comment: Probably the reason of the slider doesn't work is jQuery UI widgets needs to integrate support for touch events on mobile version, which is done in jQuery UI Touch Punch project. Simply include the script on your page and your touch events will be turned into their corresponding mouse events to which jQuery UI will respond as expected.